# Regex for route matching in Express

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I'm not very good with regular expressions, so I want to make sure I'm doing this correctly. Let's say I have two very similar routes, `/discussion/:slug/` and `/page/:slug/`. I want to create a route that matches both these pages.

```
app.get('/[discussion|page]/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
  ...enter code here...
})
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Right now I'm just creating two separate routes.

```
someFunction = function(req, res, next) {..}
app.get('/discussion/:slug', someFunction)
app.get('/page/:slug', someFunction)
```

Comment: Are you confident on the `[]` brackets for alternation? That'd be the first time I've seen them used in this way. (Parens `()` are more common in more tools -- I just don't know your specific tool.)

Comment: whoops, typo. but i'm trying to find examples for express and i can't find any (or I don't know the terms to search).

Comment: just make 'someFunction' the same exact function, this is way easier to do, maybe you already have done this

Comment: In such a case app.get(['/discussion/:slug', /page/:slug'], function(req, res, next) {
  ...enter code here...
}) is also an option.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`app.get('/:type(discussion|page)/:id', ...)` works

Comment: I think the key point of this is that you can assign the request parameter to the regex by placing it in "( )" after the param name

IE: 
`:type(<regex>)` will set 
`req.params.type` to the matched string

You can't put the regex before the variable.

Comment: This syntax looks great, but doesn't seem to be documented at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html at all :-(

Comment: @rjmunro It's documented in the `path-to-regexp` module, which Express uses.  (This is mentioned in the Express docs but, yeah, it's easy to overlook.)  See https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

Comment: Thanks, it is works for me. However it seems `case sensitive` set to `false` by default. Can I set it to true? This seems to be the official docs [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#usage)

Answer (score 72):

You should use a literal javascript regular expression object, not a string, and @sarnold is correct that you want parens for alternation. Square brackets are for character classes.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express.createServer();
app.get(/^\/(discussion|page)\/(.+)/, function (req, res, next) {
  res.write(req.params[0]); //This has "discussion" or "page"
  res.write(req.params[1]); //This has the slug
  res.end();
});

app.listen(9060);
```

The `(.+)` means a slug of at least 1 character must be present or this route will not match. Use `(.*)` if you want it to match an empty slug as well.

Comment: Is there a way to use this without regex and as a string? I prefer keyword params instead of a list.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to use a string with named params if you need the sophisticated matching abilities of regular expressions. TJ says something to this effect in the express documentation. I believe it is ultimately a limitation of javascript regular expression objects.

Comment: you can do this `app.get(new RegExp('(your|string)\/here'), function…`

Comment: Your regexp isn't anchored at the start of the url.  Does express explicitly anchor or should the regexp be /\/(discussion|pa...

Comment: It should be `/^\/(discussion|page)\/(.+)/` as suggested by the user above. I've suggested an edit.

Comment: Don't forget to terminate the expression too.  e.g `/^\/(your|string)+$/`

Comment: Yeah, without `\/` in the beginning there's some weird behavior. Should always be there.