# Combine Routes in Express 4.0

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to combine these by using only one app.route? Express 4.0:

```
  app.route('/posts/:id')
    .get(post.findById)
    .put(post.updatePost)
    .delete(post.deletePost);

  app.route('/posts')
    .get(post.findAll)
    .post(post.addPost);
```

Comment: what do you mean with "combine these routes"?

Comment: Use only one .route and define the rest of the methods.

Comment: No it's not possible. What's wrong with having two .route() calls? i think this is already quite elegant.

Comment: no major problem with this but since they are all related thought it would be nice. That way one could assume each route would map to all API instances for that location.

Comment: Regex maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858005/regex-for-route-matching-in-express ..... i hate regex

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted, seems like a valid question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
router
.get('/posts', post.findAll )
.post('/posts', post.addPost )
.get('/posts/:id', post.findById )
.delete('/posts/:id', post.deletePost )
.put('/posts/:id', post.updatePost );
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to combine these two routes in an elegant way, this would be considered the correct way to create these routes.