# Is it possible to capture requests in Express using Express's regex without using a variable?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I was reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665354/1258945 and instead of:

```
app.get('/:type(discussion|page)/:id', ...)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
app.get('/(discussion|page)/:id', ...)
```

Is this possible?  I need to capture parameters in the URL (in this case :id), but I don't need to know which URL was used (that is, I don't need to capture :type).  When I try the latter, I get back

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?(?:([^/]+?))|page)\/(?:([^/]+?))\/?$/: Invalid group
```

Is it possible to capture both parameters AND a variable path?

Comment: I've been investigating, and `app.get('/discussion|page/:id', ...)` _almost_ does what I want.  `/page/:id` works as expected, but when I use `/discussion/:id` the route is captured but `:id` is undefined.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's a syntax error in your outermost non-capturing group (assuming you meant to write one). Also, the last non-capturing group is superfluous:

```
/^\/(?(?:([^/]+?))|page)\/(?:([^/]+?))\/?$/
```

should probably be

```
/^\/(?:(?:([^/]+?))|page)\/([^/]+?)\/?$/
      ^                    ^
```

Comment: That's what Express outputs when I use `app.get('/(discussion|page)/:id', ...)`.  I'm guessing it's an issue with the (discussion|page) portion, in that it's invalid syntax.  Is there valid syntax which would output a valid regex group?