# ExpressJs : Differentiating between two similar routes

Tags: node.js, express

I have two routes `/api/persons/:personId` and `/api/persons/contact`,where `:personId` is an ObjectId.

When i am hitting `api/persons/contactS` (with an 'S' character),it is hitting the API code for `api/persons/:personId` instead of giving 404.

So how can i distinguish between the two routes.I want to restrict my code control upfront where i define my routes before giving the handle to controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Express depends](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#route-paths) on [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) for parsing route paths, which supports [specifying custom patterns](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.0.3#custom-match-parameters) with placeholders:

```
app.get('/api/persons/:personId([\\dA-Fa-f]+)', ...);

app.get('/api/persons/contact', ...);
```

You can also use [`app.param()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) to validate `personId` when it might be used:

```
app.param('personId', function (req, res, next, id) {
    Persons.findById(id, function (err, person) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);
        if (!person)
            return next('route');

        req.person = person;
        next();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some kind of validation on the req, server side.  It's doing that because it's thinking you are sending it a personId.  I am sure your personId's match a certain format, so add some validation that checks the format of the personId.  If it doesn't match, return 404 (or whatever error suits your case)

For example,

```
var x = req.params.personId
if (x.length !== 10 || x.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null; ) {
  res.send(404)
}
```

This would make sure that the personId contains 10 numbers before even accepting it as a personId.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex in your route to distinguish what could be a `personId` (maybe it's all digits) and what's not.

There's an example of using regex in the route here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13665354/280842

Comment: I have done that too.. But it does not look the cause. I want to restrict my code control upfront before giving the handle to controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it give a 404? `contactS` could be a valid `personId`.

You will need to add a regular expression to the route

```
/api/persons/:personId
```

So that it only matches against valid ObjectId's, and then it will ignore `contactS` and return a 404.