# path pattern which matches only 6 symbols hashes in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to write a pattern like:

```
.get('/:pattern' ...
```

which matches only 6 symbols hashes?
How can I get this hash inside handler function?
Example of a hash: `mBe8s0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for route matching in Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858005/regex-for-route-matching-in-express)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
app.get('/:pattern([A-Za-z0-9]{5}$)', function (req, res){
    res.send(req.params.pattern);
});
```

Comment: How can I get a value of `:pattern` in such case?

Comment: You can use req.url, which returns /pattern   So just remove slash and you can use pattern

Comment: Surely this matches 5 characters not 6?