# is there a way to get "rest of route" with express req.params?

Tags: express

For example if the route is `/share/path/to/something`

can I set something up where I can get the string "/path/to/something" which might have an arbitrary number of slashes?

`router.get('/share/:theResOfTheRoute', ...`

I could set up a param for each part between the slashes but I don't know beforehand how many slashes there might be

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for route matching in Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858005/regex-for-route-matching-in-express)

Comment: See the linked article, you just use regular expressions.