# Using regular expression in express router

Tags: node.js, express

attempting to match the following router

```
# GET /measurements/2013-10-10T16:20:00.000Z
```

Currently using this code:

```
var router = express.router();
router.get(/measurements\/:date(.*Z$), ResultCtrl.processRequest)
```

what am I missing here ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858005/regex-for-route-matching-in-express

Comment: this did the job..router.get(/measurements\/(\d{1,4}.+[zZ]$)/, MeasurementCtrl.getBasedOnISODate);

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
router.get('/measurements/:date(^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}Z$)', ResultCtrl.processRequest)
```

That will match a timestamp of the form `####-##-##T##:##:##.###Z`, where each `#` is a digit.

Comment: i got that.. wanted something more specific

Comment: More specific how? A more specific regex, you mean?

Comment: Perhaps `/^\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}T(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$/`