# Express Router reading two different dynamic routes the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I specify an optional parameter with Express Router? This [resource](https://debugmode.net/2014/03/31/understanding-routing-of-expressjs-in-node-js/) says to use `?` after the param.

Basically, I usually hit `/posts` endpoint just to get all posts. But sometimes I need to add in a `type` filter and get all Posts based on that type. The routing instead is reading my `/posts/:id` as the same dynamic route as `/posts/:type` and so when I need to make a `getOne` request from `/posts/:id`, it doesn't ever hit that because it hits `/:type` instead and does a regular `Posts.get`.

These are different routes, but `Router` is reading them as the same.

React frontend:

```
getPosts(type) {
    return http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${url}/${type}`,
        data: data
    });
}
```

NodeJS Express Router backend:

```
/* Posts CRUD */
router.route('/posts/:type?')
  .get(Posts.get)
  .post(Posts.post);

/* Post CRUD */
router.route('/posts/:id')
  .get(Posts.getOne)
  .put(Posts.put)
  .delete(Posts.delete);
```

**To clarify**: I need routes with `:type` param to do a `.get(Posts.get)` and routes with `:id` param to do a `.get(Posts.getOne)`

Comment: If you wish to keep the initial path the same for both, you need to restrict what matches the `:type` route so that matches to the `:id` route will not match but get passed on to the `:id` route. As you currently have it, everything that matches the `:id` route also is matched by the `:type` route. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10858005/5812121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the doc, it says that if you put a parameter between : & ?, that parameter is optional i.e.

```
app.get('/route/:id/:op?',...)
```

means that I can have `'/route/1'` as well as `'/route/1/delete'` as endpoint.

For your situation, you have to use different route for one of them to remove ambiguity.

Better use `router.route('/post/:id')` for getting one item as `posts` is plural anyways :)